# PHP IBM DB2 Error

Tags: php, db2, ibm-midrange

I am seeing this error message in the error log

```
42704: TABLE in USERNAME type *FILE not found. SQLCODE=-204
```

This error message was not produced before this week. I think it has something to do with the IBM system and not with the PHP/SQL code. I spent all day yesterday trying to figure it out but have no idea still. I am pretty sure the library that has the TABLE in it is in the users profile on the system so I don't understand why it says it can't find it.

Comment: error code is described here. if you haven't already checked, this link may help you. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v6r2mx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wps.z.620.doc/doc/rins_zos_sql204_516.html

Comment: If the host system is a midrange (Power system), the zOS (mainframe) DB2 reference may not be a perfect fit.  As with any problem, once one figures out what has changed, one usually has a resolution.

Comment: Well before my SQL statements looked something like "SELECT * FROM table" and I've been changing them to "SELECT * FROM library.table" and they are working again. I don't know enough about the IBM system to understand what has changed as I do mostly PHP/Web development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a library list or current library issue.  See this related question and answer for more information that may be helpful: [Odbc connection string format, not finding files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172879/odbc-connection-string-format-not-finding-files/8173354#8173354)

Comment: Agreed, this is a library list issue.