# odbc_connect set DefaultSchema

Tags: php, odbc, ibm-midrange

I want to try to define the schema to set list of libraries where I can search the table on which make the query sql.

at the momenti I can connect on my DB2 into IBMi with this string-connection:

```
 $user = 'USER';
 $password = 'PWD';
 $hostname = '192.168.1.100';
 $db = 'S6528B5A';
 $conn_string = "DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC  Driver};
                 SYSTEM=$hostname;
                 PROTOCOL=TCPIP;
                 UID=$user;
                 PWD=$password;
                 DATABASE=$db;
                 DefaultSchema={LIB1,LIB2};";
```

the connection is successfully established i get Resource id #3 but when i try to execute sql query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM FILE1';
$rows = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
```

I get an error SQL state S0002 where the file is not found (as if searching for the file in wrong library, search in the library with the same user name that opened the connection)

how can set my environment at the first connectione and than execute query?

Answer (score 3):

Use this connection string to enable system naming and to not set a default library:

```
$conn_string = "DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC  Driver};
  SYSTEM=$hostname;
  PROTOCOL=TCPIP;
  UID=$user;
  PWD=$password;
  Naming=1;
  DefaultSchema=,LIB1,LIB2;";
```

---

[Client Access ODBC: Default Libraries Setting](http://www-912.ibm.com/s_dir/slkbase.NSF/0/2554db904e5a601b862565c2007cc4b8?OpenDocument)

[ODBC connection string keywords](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaik/connectkeywords.htm)

Excerpts of the relevant parts are:

*With SQL naming convention, the operating system does not perform a library list search to locate an unqualified object. If a default collection is defined, the default collection is used to resolve unqualified SQL statements.*

...

*With the SYS naming convention, the unqualified SQL statements go to the default collection. If there is no default collection, the current library is used. If no current library is specified, the library list is used.*

...

*Default Collection*

*A job attribute set by ODBC that determines the library used when processing SQL statements that contain unqualified SQL names. When a default collection is set all unqualified objects except procedures, functions and types must reside in the default collection, regardless of naming convention.*

...

**How can I get ODBC to search the library list?**

*As explained above, edit the ODBC data source and set system naming to SYS. The default library must be empty, or on versions older than R510, the default libraries setting must start with a comma so that no default collection is defined (for example, ",MYLIB1, MYLIB2").*

---

[Odbc connection string format, not finding files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8173354/58061)